# Error datos duplicados al subir información a base de datos por medio de un archivo csv en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

copie un codigo que encontre en internet, para subir información a mi base de datos por medio de un archivo csv con php, pero al subir la información me aparecen registros duplicados.

Este es mi codigo para subir el archivo csv:

```
$manifiesto = $_GET['manifiesto'];

$tipo       = $_FILES['dataCliente']['type'];
$tamanio    = $_FILES['dataCliente']['size'];
$archivotmp = $_FILES['dataCliente']['tmp_name'];
$lineas     = file($archivotmp);

$i = 0;
  
foreach ($lineas as $linea) { 
    $cantidad_registros = count($lineas);
    $cantidad_regist_agregados =  ($cantidad_registros);

    if ($i != 0) {

        $datos = explode(";", $linea);
       
        $fecha_descargue_real                = !empty($datos[0])  ? ($datos[0]) : '';
        $planta         = !empty($datos[1])  ? ($datos[1]) : '';
        $remesa_inicial               = !empty($datos[2])  ? ($datos[2]) : '';
        $tipo                   = !empty($datos[3])  ? ($datos[3]) : '';
        $placa               = !empty($datos[4])  ? ($datos[4]) : '';
        $transportadora               = !empty($datos[5])  ? ($datos[5]) : '';
        $remesa_corona               = !empty($datos[6])  ? ($datos[6]) : '';
        $documento               = !empty($datos[7])  ? ($datos[7]) : '';
        $remision_padre               = !empty($datos[8])  ? ($datos[8]) : '';
        $remision_hija               = !empty($datos[9])  ? ($datos[9]) : '';
        $cliente               = !empty($datos[10])  ? ($datos[10]) : '';
        $direccion_entrega               = !empty($datos[11])  ? ($datos[11]) : '';
        $ciudad               = !empty($datos[12])  ? ($datos[12]) : '';
        $referencia               = !empty($datos[13])  ? ($datos[13]) : '';
        $cantidad               = !empty($datos[14])  ? ($datos[14]) : '';
        $peso               = !empty($datos[15])  ? ($datos[15]) : '';
        
                    
                    $insertarData = "INSERT INTO infocarga(fecha_descargue_real, planta, remesa_inicial, tipo_servicio, placa, documento, remesa_corona, transportadora, remision, remision_hija, clientes, direccion_entrega, ciudad, referencia, cantidad, peso, responsable,  fecha_creacion,  estado, fecha_entrega, fecha_subida_servidor, responsable_subida_servidor, motivo, detalle, motivo2, atribuido_a, novedades, valor_negociado, averias, valor_averias, cobrar, valor_facturado, factura_sinergia, fecha_factura) VALUES(  
                        '".$fecha_descargue_real."',  
                        '".$planta."', 
                        '".$remesa_inicial."',  
                        '".$tipo."', 
                        '".$placa."', 
                        '".$documento."', 
                        '".$remesa_corona."', 
                        '".$transportadora."', 
                        '".$remision_padre."',  
                        '".$remision_hija."',  
                        '".$cliente."',  
                        '".$direccion_entrega."',  
                        '".$ciudad."', 
                        '".$referencia."', 
                        '".$cantidad."', 
                        ".$peso.", 
                        '".$_SESSION['nombre']."', 
                        NOW(), 
                        'PENDIENTE POR RECIBO', 
                        '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', '', '', '', '0000-00-00')";
                    
                    if ($conn->query($insertarData) === TRUE) {
                        echo "";
                    }else{
                        echo "Error ". $conn->error;
                    }
  }

 $i++;
}
```

al subir el archivo no muiestra ningun error, pero me aparece duplicadas las lineas con diferente ID en base de datos.

quisiera que el codigo no subiera lineas repetidas puesto que esto me ha funcionado muy bien.

Comment: Quizás es una pregunta tonta, pero verificaste que los datos en el CSV no son duplicados?

Comment: Hola, si valide hasta con 3 lineas y aun asi me duplica la data.

Comment: la pregunta es si hay datos duplicados en el csv ... no si se duplica en la base de datos que es obvio que si esta ocurriendo ...

Comment: yo tengo otra pregunta ... como envias los datos del navegador al servidor? ajax+boton o un boton separado para el submit???

Comment: es importante ya que aveces se triggerea dos veces los click en los botones ...

Comment: en el archivo csv, no hay data repetida, y se envia por medio de un boton.

Comment: Abre tu archivo csv con algún editor de texto y cerciorate de que el carácter delimitador es ``;`` y no ``,`` u otro.

Comment: ya revise esa parte y todo esta delimitado por **;** en la revisión que hice no identifico error en el archivo, parece ser que el problema esta en el codigo pero no logro encontrarlo.